# Clearing ListBox value (not listBox items)

Tags: c#

Any idea how can I clear only data calculated by "Calculate" button (my variable value) and leave the text in my listBox unchanged. 
So that's the display data of my listBox:

```
listBox1.Items[0] = listBox1.Items[0].ToString() + "  " + financeRequired.ToString();
```

that displays like that in my listBox:
users finance required: $2000

Tried using: `listBox1.Items[0] = ""; and listbox1.Items.Clear();` but that is just clearing the whole listBox and I need the text: "users finance required:" I have defined in the listbox (listBox1.Items[0] = listBox1.Items[0].ToString()) to remain visible and only value $2000 (financeRequired.ToString()) to be cleared so new calculation is possible.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and sorry for looooong story ;)

Comment: Can you post some actual code (please format it - not just as text)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, to populate with a calculated value you can do this...

```
listBox1.Items[0].Text = $"users finance required: {financeRequired}";
```

and to remove the calculated value you can do this...

```
listBox1.Items[0].Text = $"users finance required:";
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! just needed to enter each listBox.Item.Text value I have originally declared in the listBox (iems 0, 1, 2 3....). Simple and brilliant! Thank you very much Archer :)